# Find all external resources in a css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the best way to parse a css file, and get a list of all the css (using @imports), and the images that are referenced as background-images etc? Is there any parser for css available in ruby??

Comment: What problem are you wanting to solve? If it's to compact resources and manage data URIs or whatnot, check out Jammit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/docs.html) to parse stylesheets to validate their syntax among other things.

```
require 'less'
Less.parse "div { width: 1 + 1 }"
```